# I have created new Qna Maker App and service using ARM template While creating the KB i am getting no Endpoint Key Found

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have created new Qna Maker App and service using ARM template
While creating the KB i am getting no Endpoint Key Found

Answer (score 0):

After you create the Azure service with the ARM template, you must create a knowledge base using the QnA Maker portal, REST APIs or SDKS. the Knowledge base (KB) then needs to be publised. After the KB is published, you can query with the endpoint.

The resource key shown in the Azure portal for the QnA Maker resource is NOT the key to use when querying the endpoint. That querying key is shown when you published the KB using the [QnA Maker portal](https://qnamaker.ai).